# Fetching the website with Facebook Sharing Debugger causes an error

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, next.js, vercel

I'm pulling my hair out for two days now, trying to figure out why Facebook Sharing Debugger can't fetch my next.js website properly. The website is hosted on Vercel.

When I fetch it with Postman or browser there are no errors (in Vercel log and a console). The server returns HTML and status code 200. However when I fetch it with facebook sharing debugger:
[See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Ffaktypolityczne-8dkcps35j.now.sh) I got this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body><p>An error occurred with this application.

NO_STATUS_CODE_FROM_FUNCTION
</p></body>
</html>
```

The response code is 502.

Vercel console shows this error:

```
[GET] /
23:19:43:38
Status:
-1
Duration:
2881.85ms
Memory Used:
54 MB
ID:
jkth8-1589318383376-c2fb8a7f81a0
User Agent:
facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
2020-05-12T21:19:46.290Z    a0145e40-064f-4313-9d63-068d4fd882c7    WARN    the options [servers] is not supported
2020-05-12T21:19:46.290Z    a0145e40-064f-4313-9d63-068d4fd882c7    WARN    the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
2020-05-12T21:19:46.290Z    a0145e40-064f-4313-9d63-068d4fd882c7    WARN    the options [dbName] is not supported
2020-05-12T21:19:46.290Z    a0145e40-064f-4313-9d63-068d4fd882c7    WARN    the options [srvHost] is not supported
2020-05-12T21:19:46.290Z    a0145e40-064f-4313-9d63-068d4fd882c7    WARN    the options [credentials] is not supported
2020-05-12T21:19:46.291Z    a0145e40-064f-4313-9d63-068d4fd882c7    ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './public/fact-title-img-8bf01afa.jpeg'","code":"ENOENT","errno":-2,"syscall":"open","path":"./public/fact-title-img-8bf01afa.jpeg","stack":["Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './public/fact-title-img-8bf01afa.jpeg'"]}
Unknown application error occurred
```

The error is related to my function that saves the binary data fetched from MongoDB as a file, in a `public` folder, so I can use it in a react component.

What the heck is going on here? Why facebook GET works differently then Postman GET?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple. I safely return an error in fs.writeFile callback instead of throwing it which terminates the process. 
I have no idea why error occures only when facebook fetches the website.